# Extend a div's width beyond 100% when user zooms

Tags: javascript, css

A `div` contains an SVG (D3 graph) and has its `width` set to `100%`. The size cannot be set to a fixed point because the page should feel responsive.

Expected behaviour: When the user zooms in (`ctrl +`), the SVG should become bigger, more readable.

Actual behaviour: The SVG shrinks because the surrounding elements (header, navigation etc) take up more space, which means less space for the SVG. Zooming out makes the SVG grow.

What I've tried:

```
/* JS */
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--zoom-ratio', `${window.devicePixelRatio}`)
```

```
/* CSS */
.foo-container {
    overflow: auto;
}
.foo {
    width: calc(var(--zoom-ratio) * 100%);
}
```

This works, as long as someone uses a screen with a 1:1 pixel ratio. 4k laptop displays are often set to 200-250%, which means that the SVG uses more than twice as much space as it should. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the provided answer wasn't quite what I was looking for but I found a hack that seems to work well enough. If someone finds a better solution in the future, I will mark that one as the correct answer. Until then, the following worked for me:

```
  const calcZoomRoughly = (): number => Math.floor(window.outerWidth * 16 * (1 / window.innerWidth)) * (1 / 16);
  const prevRatio = { zoomRatio: calcZoomRoughly() };
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const currentRatio = calcZoomRoughly();
    if (Math.abs(prevRatio.zoomRatio - currentRatio) < 0.01) return;
    prevRatio.zoomRatio = currentRatio;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--zoom-ratio', `${currentRatio}`);
  });
```

It uses `outerWidth` and `innerWidth` to figure out the ratio. `innerWidth` is affected by zoom, while `outerWidth` isn't and system settings affect both, so the ratio stays the same. `outerWidth` also includes browser borders and drag handles, which means `outerWidth / innerWidth` is slightly larger than `1.0` if the browser is not in fullscreen mode. So the raw zoom ratio itself is not enough but I round it to an accuracy of `1/16`, which seems to work decently well with modern UIs (needs more testing) and hopefully avoids floating point rounding issues better than something like `1/10`.

If the `resize` event is triggered (and zooming in/out triggers the event) the handler does a quick check if the ratio actually changed meaningfully (again, avoid float errors) and if it did it sets a CSS variable `--zoom-ratio` that can then be used throughout the project. Don't forget to initialize it to `1.0` in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience its best to have initial value calculated on the BOXSIZE/WindowSize and calculate the Content relative to the box/window
this will overcome issues of diferent devices accessing the content
than add listener to change the view on window size change
Example:

```
function adjustSvgSize() {
    const svgContainer = document.querySelector('.foo-container');
    const svgElement = svgContainer.querySelector('svg');

    // Assuming your SVG has a viewBox defined like "0 0 width height"
    // You can preserve the aspect ratio while scaling.
    const viewBox = svgElement.viewBox.baseVal;
    const aspectRatio = viewBox.width / viewBox.height;

    // Calculate new dimensions based on the container's width
    // and the SVG's aspect ratio
    const newWidth = svgContainer.offsetWidth;
    const newHeight = newWidth / aspectRatio;

    // Optionally, adjust the SVG dimensions (if needed)
    svgElement.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
    svgElement.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;
}

// Initial adjustment
adjustSvgSize();

// Adjust on window resize
window.addEventListener('resize', adjustSvgSize);
```